# Store the name but not the path of all folders in a specified folder to a list?

Tags: c#, windows, list, path, directory

So I have a folder in the same directory as my .exe console application. I want to make a list of all the folders inside of that folder (it's called `ClientFiles`) but I don't want the full paths. So if I have a hierarchy like this:

```
ClientFiles

---\ Folder1

---\ Folder2

---\ Folder3
```

I should end up with a list containing the strings: "Folder1", "Folder2", "Folder3".

This is what I have right now:

```
List<string> clientNumbers = Directory
  .GetDirectories(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ClientFiles\\")
  .ToList<string>();
```

but the list it's returning contains the full path for each element. Any quick way to resolve this? I guess I could foreach through and remove the preceding path text but that seems so extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can accomplish this.

The first is simply removing the component you already know:

```
string directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ClientFiles\\";
List<string> clientNumbers = Directory
  .GetDirectories(directory)
  .Select(x => x.Substring(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Length - 1)
  .ToList();
```

Assuming you only want the file's name (or folder's name if it's a folder object), you can use the [`Path` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
List<string> clientNumbers = Directory
  .GetDirectories(directory)
  .Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Don't want fileNames, specifically only folder names are desired here.

Comment: @CapnJack It's a bit misleading of a function name, but `Path.GetFileName(string)` it will give you the folder name if it's a folder object.

Comment: wow that is misleading, but it works! Going to mark your as answer for the simplest response. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of LINQ:

```
List<string> clientNumbers = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ClientFiles\\")
.Select(x => x.Replace(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ClientFiles\\", "")).ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect this is what I had in mind. However I'm going to mark JNYRanger's response as answer since it's a little simpler.

Comment: Each to their own I suppose ;). But glad this is cleared up for you

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.Select(x=>x.Split('\').LastOrDefault())` at the end such as:

```
List<string> clientNumbers = Directory.GetDirectories(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ClientFiles\\").ToList<string>()
   .Select(x=>x.Split('\').LastOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a LINQ lambda expression:

```
List<string> clientNumbers = Directory.GetDirectories(
                             AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ClientFiles\\")
                             .ToList<string>().Select(s=>s.Split("\\").Last());
```

LastOrDefault will return same, as string is nullable